# Я хочу запрашивать содержимое квадратного списка по спирали. range функция зачем-то прибавляет 1 к y

Tags: python-3.x

```
res=32
reshalf=res/2
spisok=[[0 for x in range(res)] for y in range(res)]
def spiral(count):
    global reshalf
    i=0
    y=0
    r=range(count)
    while True:
        while True:
            for x in range(4):
                print(y)#debug, returns 0
                for z in range(y):
            for z in range(y+1):
                b=a=reshalf
                if x==0:
                    b-=y-z
                    a+=z
                elif x==1:
                    a+=y-z
                    b+=z
                elif x==2:
                    b+=y-z
                    a-=z
                elif x==3:
                    a-=y-z
                    b-=z
                if b in range(res) and a in range(res):
                    yield b,a
                i+=1
                if i not in r or not y:
                    break
                    print(y)#debug, returns 1!!!
                    b=a=reshalf
                    if x==0:
                        b-=y-z
                        a+=z
                    elif x==1:
                        a+=y-z
                        b+=z
                    elif x==2:
                        b+=y-z
                        a-=z
                    elif x==3:
                        a-=y-z
                        b-=z
                    if b in range(res) and a in range(res):
                        yield b,a
                    i+=1
                    if i not in r:
                        break
                if i not in r:
                    break
            if i not in r:
                break
            y+=1
        i=1
        y=1

for y,x in spiral(13):
    print(y,x)
```

Короче, после первого использования range y растёт на 1, чего не должно происходить, так как y++ совсем в другом месте. Вместо 16,16 функция возвращает 15, 16.
Должно быть:

```
     5
  12 1 6
11 4 0 2 7
  10 3 8
     9
```

Добавлено: к этому времени я уже сам додумался.

Ответ:

```
res=32
reshalf=res/2
spisok=[[0 for x in range(res)] for y in range(res)]
def spiral(count):
    i=1
    y=1
    r=range(count)
    b=a=reshalf
    yield b,a
    while True:
        while True:
            for x in range(4):
                print(y)
                for z in range(y):
                    b=a=reshalf
                    if x==0:
                        b-=y-z
                        a+=z
                    elif x==1:
                        a+=y-z
                        b+=z
                    elif x==2:
                        b+=y-z
                        a-=z
                    elif x==3:
                        a-=y-z
                        b-=z
                    if b in range(res) and a in range(res):
                        yield b,a
                    i+=1
                    if i not in r:
                        break
                if i not in r:
                    break
            if i not in r:
                break
            y+=1
        i=1
        y=1

for y,x in spiral(13):
    print(y,x)
```

Заметил ещё пару ошибок, теперь:

```
def spiral(count):
    global reshalf
    while True:
        i=1
        y=1
        yield reshalf,reshalf
        while True:
            for x in range(4):
                for z in range(y):
                    b=a=reshalf
                    if x==0:
                        b-=y-z
                        a+=z
                    elif x==1:
                        a+=y-z
                        b+=z
                    elif x==2:
                        b+=y-z
                        a-=z
                    elif x==3:
                        a-=y-z
                        b-=z
                    if b in range(res) and a in range(res):
                        yield b,a
                        i+=1
                    if i >= count:
                        break
                if i >= count:
                    break
            if i >= count:
                break
            y+=1
```

Comment: ну если вы сами определили, где неправильно, в чём, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: ничего я не определил. это похоже на баг.

Comment: всё выглядит правильным.

Comment: если я ошибаюсь, пайтоновый способ?

Comment: copy.copy(y) ничего не даёт.

Comment: nonlocal y тоже

Comment: других вариантов не знаю.

Comment: я определил, что неправильно, а не где и почему.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [creating a spiral array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36834505/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если 'y' равен 0, то вот этот цикл

```
for z in range(y):
```

выполнится ноль раз (то есть ни разу не выполнится, как подсказывает кэп).

Соответственно, программа пропускает этот цикл, выполняет строчку, где увеличивается 'y' и идёт на следующую итерацию цикла `for x in range(4)`